# Amazon web service with ios integration

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

all,
I am new to AWS world.
I am creating a app like photo sharing using ios 7 sdk and aws mobile sdk.I have read DynamoDB and trying to use that.
I Have used Cognito features.
Also required SignUp and SignIn features. How to implement signup/signin features?
Can you put some code here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using parse.com instead.

It provides all the features you need, along with a great ios sdk.

I have a app on the ios store using parse as the backend

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know about Parse.com and used in another app. But for this app I need AWS.